# How to use a session manager in neovim?

Tags: neovim

So I just installed neovim with [nvchad](https://nvchad.com/) and plans to use it as my default code editor and a session manager is essential to me. I installed [persisted.nvim](https://github.com/olimorris/persisted.nvim) using Lazy as my package manager. The package manager downloaded the plugin but I wasn't sure if it is being used or is being loaded as when I run any of the commands listed in the [docs](https://github.com/olimorris/persisted.nvim). Neovim says that it is not an editor command.

Here is my plugins.lua file located at `~/.config/nvim/lua/custom`

```
{
    "olimorris/persisted.nvim",
    config = true,
}
```

When I run `:Lazy` I see that persisted.nvim is installed and is not loaded but I still cannot run any of the commands.

Am I missing out on something?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the plugin is not being loaded at the start of nvim since I am using LazyNvim. I added `lazy = false` and everything worked as intended.

```
{
    "olimorris/persisted.nvim",
    lazy = false,
    config = true,
}
```